# How to filter a boolean in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, boolean

So I need to use these for true and false:

> "pe-7s-close-check pe-lg  pe-va text-success"  "pe-7s-close-circle
> pe-lg pe-va text-danger".

I have a html code:

```
<tr *ngFor="let invoice of invoices; let i = index">
                            <td>{{ i + 1 }}</td>
                            <td>{{ invoice.number }}</td>
                            <td>{{ invoice.client.name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ invoice.paid }}</td>
```

invoice.paid is the boolean here,so when its paid it sould be green when not paid red how should I  do it?
Something like this picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tr *ngFor="let invoice of invoices; let i = index">
  <td>{{ i + 1 }}</td>
  <td>{{ invoice.number }}</td>
  <td>{{ invoice.client.name }}</td>
  <td>
  <i [ngClass]="{'pe-7s-close-check pe-lg pe-va text-success': invoice.paid, 'pe- 
  7s-close-circle pe-lg pe-va text-danger': !invoice.paid}"></i>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`<td [ngClass]="{invoice.paid ? 'pe-7s-close-check pe-lg pe-va text-success' : 'pe-7s-close-circle pe-lg pe-va text-danger'}"></td>`

[Angular ngClass directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)